# Shorter version python code block , using file.write

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I am a beginner in python, wondering if there is shorter version to this code block.I am trying to write table of eight to file.

```
i = 1
file = open('table.txt', 'w')
while i<=10:
    inputf = str(8*i)
    file.write('8 * ')
    file.write(str(i))
    file.write(' = ')
    file.write(inputf)
    file.write('\n')
    i = i+1
file.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `f-string` like below:

```
i = 1
file = open('table.txt', 'w')
while i<=10:
    file.write(f' 8 * {i} = {8*i} \n')
    i = i+1
file.close()
```

By thanks @BNilsou With `for-loop`:

```
file = open('table.txt', 'w')
for i in range(1,11):
    file.write(f' 8 * {i} = {8*i} \n')
file.close()
```

Output: *(in table.txt)*

```
 8 * 1 = 8 
 8 * 2 = 16 
 8 * 3 = 24 
 8 * 4 = 32 
 8 * 5 = 40 
 8 * 6 = 48 
 8 * 7 = 56 
 8 * 8 = 64 
 8 * 9 = 72 
 8 * 10 = 80
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll get the same result with:

```
with open('table.txt', 'w') as fh:
    for i in range(1, 11):
        fh.write(f'8 * {i} = {8*i}\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("table.txt", "w") as file:
    for i in range(1, 11):
        print(f'8 * {i} = {8 * i}', file=file)
```

is about the shortest in lines you can get.

Comment: TILT `print()` has a file parameter!

Comment: It also has `sep`, `end` and `flush` :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
file = open('table.txt', 'w')
for i in range(1, 11):
    statement = '8 * ' + (str(i)) + ' = ' + str(8*i) + '\n'
    file.write(statement)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all the write lines and convert it to one:
`file.write("8*",i,"=",inputf,"\n")`

Answer (score 0):

```
open("table.txt", "w").write("\n".join([f'8 * {i} = {8 * i}' for i in range(1, 11)]))
```

It's the shortest way, but it's very bad way :)